# Raw Input on for loops

Tags: python, input

I want to print something out on a raw input that is in a for loop

```
for x in doclist:
    if x == '[':
        count=count+1
    elif count == 1:
        response=raw_input("Please enter", x)
        count=count-1
    else:
        pass
```

when I do this it gives me the error two arguments when only one is expected

I want on the raw_input to print out "Please enter (whatever x is in doclist)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want something more like this:

```
for x in doclist:
    if x == '[':
        count=count+1
    elif count == 1:
        response=raw_input("Please enter %s" % x)
        count=count-1
    else:
        pass
```

Using something like what you had only works with print.